# How to change array string to array in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am developing game backend for unity.
I used PHP backend server for it. so I get the string from PHP backend like this string.

```
["Swww","Sdss"][0,0]
```

I am gonna change to array this string.

```
string[] result1 = {"Swww", "Sdss"}
string[] result2 = {"0", "0"}
```

What should I do for this?

[image]

It is your end result.

I mean that result is next picture.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a stream of JSON arrays. Can you use a JSON parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot of solutions, you could use Split and Linq with unity3d

```
using System.Linq;
```

so: result[0) and result[1] give the final result waited

```
var st = "[<\"Swww\">,\"Sdss\"][0,0]";
var result = st.Replace(">", "").Replace("<", "").Replace("\"","")
               .Split(new char[] { ']', '[' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(s => s.Split(',').ToArray())
               .ToArray();
```

or with Regex

```
var st = "[<\"Swww\">,\"Sdss\"][0,0]";
var result = Regex.Replace(st, "[><\"]", "")
                  .Split(new char[] { ']', '[' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .Select(s => s.Split(',').ToArray())
                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi Frenchy I gonna remove <"> string in "Swww". I need addition code.

Comment: <"Swww"> or "<Swww>" ?

Comment: I need the <Swww>

Comment: anyways the solution is ok , it replaces all > and < by nothing in anyplace of string..If you have some problem with replacement i suggest you to open a new question to avoid to pollute this...because you add problem to another problem....

Comment: Sorry Frenchy. Now you misunderstand. Please see my edited question.

Comment: ok you have to eliminate double quote too?

Comment: Yes, Of course. Please share your answer.

Comment: answer edited just add " to replace

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string based on `][`. Then remove `[` and `]`. finally split based on `,`

[code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PfXMx9):

```
string input = "[\"Swww\", \"Sdss\"][0, 0]";           
var array= input.Split(new string[] { "][" }, StringSplitOptions.None);           
string[] result1 = array[0].Replace("[","").Split(new string[] { " ," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result1));
string[] result2 = array[1].Replace("]", "").Split(new string[] { " ," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change you PHP backend to spit out valid JSON. There are proven tools/types in .net ecosystem and JSON is heavily standardized. You will avoid parsing problems in future with parsing inputs like`["aa][aa","aa"][]`. Start with proven existing techniques and fallback to custom data formats and parsing if your perf will be in practice bad.